# trigger on after update does take account of all updated values

Tags: mysql, triggers

EDIT : this post is solved. I was having a stupid error. My update query was not changing the value of the changing field, the trigger was only catch the first value change. Sorry !

I have a trigger that does not take into account of all updated fields in an update query.

here is my trigger `history_transaction`, i only audit changes for `status` and `price_asked` fields of table `transac_transaction`

```
CREATE TRIGGER history_transaction
AFTER UPDATE ON transac_transaction
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF(OLD.status <> NEW.status) THEN
      INSERT INTO transac_transaction_history(transac_id, author,     old_data, new_data, date_upd)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.last_author_id_update, OLD.status, NEW.status, NOW());
    END IF;

    IF(OLD.price_asked <> NEW.price_asked) THEN
      INSERT INTO transac_transaction_history(transac_id, author, old_data, new_data, date_upd)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.last_author_id_update, OLD.price_asked, NEW.price_asked, NOW());
      END IF;
  END;
$$
```

If i execute an update such as :

```
update transac_transaction set price_asked=12.00, status=1 where id=2;
```

I will only have an insert in the audit table for the price_asked change, not the status.

Something is missing in my trigger that could loop on fields maybe ?
I think the each row does not take into account the all fields updated.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider NULL values:
Can you try modifing

```
IF(OLD.status <> NEW.status)
```

with

```
 IF(OLD.status <> NEW.status 
    OR ((OLD.status IS NULL OR NEW.status IS NULL) AND OLD.status IS NOT NULL A NEW.status IS NOT NULL) )
```

and the same for price_asked

Comment: I just realize that the trigger works nice on an other mariaDB instance and on Mysql. Maybe a version issue... I investigate...thank you for your solution

Comment: I have mariadb 10.2.3. On preprod server we have 10.0.29

Answer (score 0):

All my fault. My update query was keeping a same value for the second field...
All works fine.